# How to use environment variables in serverless.yml?

Tags: serverless

**Goal**:

- create an environment variable with the name of the DynamoDB table and use this variable in the `serverless.yml` file and in the code also.
- preferably: environment should be created in `serverless.yml` also.

**Solution:**

I try to use the environment variable in `serverless.yml` file in the following way:

- serverless.yml:

```yaml
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: java11

  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1

  environment:
    DYNAMO_DB_TABLE: "tableName"

......

resources:
  Resources:

    S3ObjectsTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: ${DYNAMO_DB_TABLE} /solution1
        TableName: ${env:DYNAMO_DB_TABLE} /solution2


............
```

- solution1:

With **solution1** I receive an error: `Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+`

- solution2:

In the documentation, I found several tips, but nothing worked for me, for example:

```yaml
service: new-service
provider: aws
functions:
  hello:
    name: ${env:FUNC_PREFIX}-hello
    handler: handler.hello
  world:
    name: ${env:FUNC_PREFIX}-world
    handler: handler.world
```

For my case (**solution2**) I receive error: `Value not found at "env" source`

I also tried to create variables in `env.yml` with `useDotenv: true` parameter in `serverless.yml` and other and other else, but nothing works for me.

---

How to correctly **create** and **use** environment variables in `serverless.yml`?

Answer (score 2):

That solution works for me:

I created `.env` file where I set the needed variables:

```
DYNAMO_DB_TABLE=s3ObjectsTable
S3_BUCKET_NAME=test-task-files
```

In this case, I can use them in the `serverless.yml` and in the project:

```
service: serverless-task
frameworkVersion: '3'

useDotenv: true

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: java11

  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1

  environment:
    DYNAMO_DB_TABLE: ${env:DYNAMO_DB_TABLE}
    ....
    enter code here
resources:
  Resources:
    S3Bucket:
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${env:S3_BUCKET_NAME}
```

From the code:

```
public static String DYNAMO_DB_TABLE_NAME = System.getenv("DYNAMO_DB_TABLE");
```

Comment: Hi there, what if I move the .env.dev, .env.xx to a different folder. How can I still use .env in serverless.yml

Comment: Did you try to use env.XXX in environment calling? DYNAMO_DB_TABLE: ${env.XXX:DYNAMO_DB_TABLE} (Sorry I have stopped working on this project and can't help you more clearly)

Answer (score 1):

You have two possibilities to use dotenv, using this plugin serverless-dotenv-plugin. When you use serverless version 3, you can use dotenv=true

Comment: I forgot to send an example.

`stage: ${STAGE}`

In serverless version 3 you don't need to use the following:

`stage: ${env:STAGE}`

Comment: Thanks. I already resolved my issue, but anyway - thx

Comment: @ValentynHruzytskyi how did you resolve it?

Comment: @arjayads I posted the answer bottom. Since I do not work the last half year I do not remember all nuances, but `.env` file definitely has an influence. Please give me know if this will work for you.